# Using AggregateApplicationBuilder with a local binder

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to aggregate different `Sink` and `Source` spring boot applications using the `AggregateApplicationBuilder` as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_aggregation

Since I expect in process communication, I don't want to setup `kafka` or `rabbitmq` binder. How to configure a local one? I found that a `spring-cloud-stream-binder-local` exists but it's in `M2` since a long time and is not embedded with a release train.

How I can use the `AggregateApplicationBuilder` with no external system dependency?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `AggregateApplicationBuilder` you don't have to configure the `binder` for the `in-process` communication of the directly bound channels within the aggregated application. The binder is required only if you need the aggregate application itself consumes messages `from` broker or produces messages `to` broker. If the aggregated application itself is self-contained, then there is no need for the `binder` at all.

Comment: I have an IAE saying that a default handler has been requested but there is no binder available

Comment: Can you share more information like stacktrace and your aggregate application configuration etc., ?

Comment: I fixed it, all my `@EnableBinding` were also annotated `@SpringBootApplication`. It was required to exclude this annotation from component scan process.